# "<>" icons not working on Ardunio Keyboard Module

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

When i run `Keyboard.print("<>");` it types out "öç"(2 turkish characters).I am on a Turkish keyboard and i don't want to change it to english because i simply am more comfortable with a Turkish keyboard.

```
#include <Keyboard.h>
#include <KeyboardLayout.h>
#include <Keyboard_da_DK.h>
#include <Keyboard_de_DE.h>
#include <Keyboard_es_ES.h>
#include <Keyboard_fr_FR.h>
#include <Keyboard_it_IT.h>
#include <Keyboard_sv_SE.h>

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
pinMode(2,INPUT);
pinMode(3,INPUT);
Keyboard.begin();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
while (digitalRead(2) == false) {
  Keyboard.print("n");
  delay(200);
}
while (digitalRead(3) == false) {
  Keyboard.print("<>");
  delay(200);
}
}
```

I want it to simply type "<>" when  pin 3 is LOW.